# Linq check to see is there any NULLs in a set of DataRows?

Tags: linq, null

I have a set DataRows and I want to check if any of the fields in any of those rows has a NULL value in it. I came up with this below, but I'm not sure because I'm nesting an ALL.

```
result.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().All(o => o.ItemArray.All(i=>i == DBNull.Value))
```

Hard to tell because I can't put a "watch" in lambdas.

Comment: You can't put a "watch" in lambdas, but you can place a breakpoint within the lambda expression, letting you view the value of o or i as the expression is evaluated.  Might come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to use `Any` (in your code you will return true if All values are null) and `AsQueryable()` is useless in this case.

```
bool nullFound = result.AsEnumerable()
                       .Any(o => o.ItemArray.Any(i=>i == DBNull.Value || i == null));
```

Then, If you need a list of all rows with some value null, just do the following:

```
var rowsWithNulls = result.AsEnumerable()
                         .Where(o => o.ItemArray.Any(i=>i == DBNull.Value || i == null))
                         .ToList();
```

P.S.

I also added a `null` check to be more safe, but if you are sure to have only `DBNull.Value`, you can remove it.

Comment: I think you meant "AsQueryable is useless", not AsEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct answer. I'm also rather new to Linq, but i believe you can do something like this;

```
result.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().SingleOrDefault(o => o.ItemArray.All(i=>i == DBNull.Value))
```

This will return an list of items or null if there aren't any. Not sure if you can also nest it, but don't see why it wouldn't be possible

Comment: Actually, this code is wrong. Your code, if there's one and only one row with **All** values null will return it, otherwise it'll return null. That's not the answer.